# python logger - can only be run once

Tags: python, logging, jupyter-notebook

I am testing the python logger with the jupyter notebook.

When I run the following example code in a freshly started kernel, it works and create the log file with the right content.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/depot/wintergreen/example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

However if I try to rerun the same code with say, for instance, the filename changed from `example.log`to `example.log2`, nothing happens, the file `example.log2` is not created.

I ended up devising that test as it seemed to me that when trying to run the logging, it would only function the very first time I am running it. What am I doin wrong here?

Comment: works for me...

Comment: @thebjorn did you tested it in jupyter notebook?

Comment: @thebjorn it's mentionned twice in the question

Comment: sorry, just saw it.  No, haven't tried it in jupyter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, `.basicConfig()` uses your `kwargs` only once. Because after first time you got handlers `logging.root.handlers`, one handler actually, so if you look in [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1713-L1804)

> ```
> def basicConfig(**kwargs):
>     ...
>     _acquireLock()
>     try:
>         if len(root.handlers) == 0:
>             ...
>     finally:
>         _releaseLock()
> ```

So since your `len(root.handlers) != 0` actual assignment of the provided arguments is not happening.

*HOW TO CHANGE WITHOUT RESTARTING:*

The only solution i came up with is for changing basic Config with calling `.basicConfig()` without restarting kernel is to:

```
for handler in logging.root.handlers:
    logging.root.removeHandler(handler)
```

Which will remove all handlers from root logger and after that you are good to set anything you want.

Comment: ok so i understand the solution is to restart the kernel if i want any changes to the `logging.basicConfig` to be taken into account am i right?

Comment: @jimbasquiat i'm still investigating into this, but it's seems the only option for now, because `logging.shutdown()` should do that, but no success. i will keep you updated if i succeed in that.:)

Comment: @jimbasquiat i've updated my answer as promised.:) Tested it, works.)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that [*basicConfig()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) function is designed to only be run once.

Per the docs: The first time it runs, it "creates a StreamHandler with a default Formatter and adding it to the root logger".  However on the second time, the "function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured for it".

One possible solution is clear the previous handler with using [*logging.root.removeHandler*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.removeHandler).  Alternatively, you can directly access *stream* attribute for open stream used by the StreamHandler instance:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(filename='abc.txt') # 1st call to basicConfig
>>> h = logging.root.handlers[0]            # get the handler
>>> h.stream.close()                        # close the current stream
>>> h.stream = open('def.txt', 'a')         # set-up a new stream
```

FWIW, *basicConfig()* was a late addition to the [*logging*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.html#module-logging) module and was intended as a [simplified short-cut API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) for common cases.  In general, whenever you have problems with *basicConfig()*, it means that it is time to use the full API which is a little less convenient but gives you more control:

```
import logging

# First pass
h = logging.StreamHandler(open('abc.txt', 'a'))
h.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
h.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s | %(message)s'))
logging.root.addHandler(h)
logging.critical('The GPU is melting')

# Later passes
logging.root.removeHandler(h)
h = logging.StreamHandler(open('def.txt', 'a'))
h.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
h.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s | %(message)s'))
logging.root.addHandler(h)
logging.critical('The CPU is getting hot too')
```